# SSRS API V2 : Get report Parameter Definition with a specified parameter value

Tags: rest, ssrs-2017

Trying to get reports parameters valid values, like you get with : `/Reports({Id})/ParameterDefinitions`

But some parameters available values are query based and have a dependency on another parameter.

I don't seem to find a way to call `ParameterDefinitions` with values other than defaults.

The goals is to update the list of available values on the end user side.

I expected, there would be a way to call `/Reports({Id})/ParameterDefinitions?${ParameterName}={Value}` or something, but none of the syntax I've tried for this works.